# Relate the singular values of $A$ and $\frac{A^T+A}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a square matrix with real entries $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that the symmetric matrix $\frac{A^T+A}{2}$ is positive definite.

Is it possible to find a relationship linking together the singular values of $\frac{A^T+A}{2}$ with the singular values of $A$?

The relationship can either be an equality or an inequality.

EDIT: I've tried some numerical examples in some $2 \times 2$ matrices and it appears that when $(A^T+A)/2$  is positive definite then the two singular values are perturbed by the same amount. For example:

**Example 1:**
$$
G=\begin{bmatrix} 100 &10\\4 & 5\end{bmatrix}
$$
Singular values of $G$:
$$ 4.5726253611256148668420314380021\\
 100.59866349662300975905062166134$$
$$
\frac{G^T+G}{2}=\begin{bmatrix} 100 &7\\7& 5\end{bmatrix}
$$
Singular values of $\frac{G^T+G}{2}$:
$$  4.4869809322513025538957048883323 \\
 100.51301906774869744610429511167$$

The difference is:
$$0.085644428874312312946326549669858\\
 0.085644428874312312946326549669858$$

**Example 2:**
$$
G=\begin{bmatrix} 20 &8\\2 & 7\end{bmatrix}
$$
Singular values of $G$:
$$  5.6287069525109683834660548089479\\
  22.02992641936769354654076803634$$
$$
\frac{G^T+G}{2}=\begin{bmatrix} 20 &5\\5& 7\end{bmatrix}
$$
Singular values of $\frac{G^T+G}{2}$:
$$  5.2993902665716374184626433863038\\
 21.700609733428362581537356613696$$

The difference is:
$$  0.32931668593933096500341142264419\\
 0.32931668593933096500341142264419$$

Comment: This looks relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31475/singular-values-of-matrix-sums

Comment: I would not trust 2x2 matrices in this case... that doesn't leave too many degrees of freedom after you take the symmetric part. In other words, if you try 3x3 and 4x4 matrices, I think you will find the deviations are not equal.

Comment: Based on a couple of tries it seems like this won't hold in the 3x3 case, but the sum of the singular values of both are quite close.

Comment: @Lepidopterist Hmm, actually adding two entries of the difference ("difference" in the sense of the examples I provided above) gives a value very close to the third entry, which is still interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\sigma_k(A)$, the $k$-th largest singular value of $A$, is always greater than or equal to $\sigma_k\left(\frac{A+A^T}2\right)$.

**Proof.** WLOG we may assume that $D=\frac{A+A^T}2$ is a positive diagonal matrix such that its diagonal entries are arranged in a decreasing order. Then $K=A-D$ is a skew symmetric matrix. By Courant-Fischer minimax principle,
$$
\sigma_k(A)=\max\limits_{\dim S=k}\ \min\limits_{x\in S,\, \|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_2.
$$
In particular, if $\tilde{A}$ denotes the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrix of $A$, $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th vector in the canonical basis and $V=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$, we have
$$
\sigma_k(A)\ge\min\limits_{x\in V,\, \|x\|_2=1} \|Ax\|_2 \ge \min\limits_{y\in \mathbb{R}^k,\, \|y\|_2=1} \|\tilde{A}y\|_2.\tag{1}
$$
Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the usual dot product on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\tilde{D}$ denotes the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrix of $D$. For any unit vector $y$, the orthogonal projection of $\tilde{A}y$ on the span of $y$ is given by $\langle \tilde{A}y,y\rangle y$. Since $\langle \tilde{A}y,y\rangle=y^T\tilde{D}y\ge D_{kk}$, it follows that $\|\tilde{A}y\|_2\ge D_{kk}$. Therefore, from $(1)$, we conclude that $\sigma_k(A)\ge D_{kk}=\sigma_k(D)$.

Comment: Sound proof, thank you very much. May I ask how you came up with this :-) ???

Comment: @niels Numerical experiments suggest that this is the case. I think there are easier proofs, but Courant-Fisher minimax principle is a standard tool for dealing with eigenvalue/singular value inequalities.

Comment: @user125056 $\langle \tilde{A}y,y\rangle y$ is the orthogonal projection of $\tilde{A}y$ onto the span of the unit vector $y$. Therefore $\|\tilde{A}y\|_2\ge|\langle \tilde{A}y,y\rangle|$. So, when $\langle \tilde{A}y,y\rangle\ge D_{kk}>0$, we obtain $\|\tilde{A}y\|_2\ge D_{kk}$.