# $\lambda_{min}\left (\frac{A+A^*}{2} \right )\leq \sigma_{min}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

For $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, how to show that
$\displaystyle \lambda_{min}\left (\frac{A+A^*}{2} \right )\leq \sigma_{min}(A)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda_\min\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)\le0$, the conclusion is obvious. So, the only interesting case is $\lambda_\min\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)>0$, i.e. when $\frac{A+A^*}2$ is positive definite. In this case, eigenvalues and singular values of $\frac{A+A^*}2$ coincide. Now your problem statement is part of a more general fact:

> If $\frac{A+A^*}2$ is positive definite, $\sigma_k\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)\le\sigma_k(A)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.

See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338199/relate-the-singular-values-of-a-and-fracata2/339457#339457) for real $A$. For complex $A$, make the appropriate modifications (e.g. transpose $\to$ conjugate transpose, skew-symmetric $\to$ skew-Hermitian, etc.).