# Relation between Sum and Product of Matrix Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

For any square matrix $A$, let $\alpha $ be the smallest eigenvalue of $%
\frac{1}{2}\left( A^{T}+A\right) $, and let $\beta $ be the largest
eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$. Does the following relationship hold
\begin{equation}
\alpha \leq \sqrt{\beta }
\end{equation}

The result is clearly true for symmetric matrices. How about general square matrices?

Comment: It's false if you allow for complex entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is true for all real square matrices. If $\alpha$ is negative, we have nothing to prove. If $\alpha$ is nonnegative, then it is also the minimum singular value of $H=\frac12(A+A^T)$ and $H$ is positive semidefinite in this case. So we are comparing the maximum singular value of $A$ with the minimum singular value of $H$. Since the $k$-th largest singular value of a matrix $A$ is always greater than or equal to the $k$-th largest singular value of $H$ when the latter is positive semidefinite (see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339457) in another thread, for instance), the result follows.

**Edit.** The last part of above answer may an overkill as it makes use of a much stronger result.  Below is a simpler answer. We only need to prove that $\lambda_\min(H)\le\sigma_1(A)$ when $H$ is positive semidefinite, but this is rather obvious because
$$
\min_{\|x\|=1}x^THx = \min_{\|x\|=1}x^TAx\le\min_{\|x\|=1}\|x\|\|Ax\|=\min_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|\le\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|.
$$
(All norms in the above line refer to the Euclidean 2-norm.)

Comment: May I ask in your [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338199/relate-the-singular-values-of-a-and-fracata2/339457#339457). How to get the second inequality in (1)? Why the subspace changes from V to R?

Comment: @user125056 *(If you have any further question concerning my answer in another thread, please make a comment in *that* thread, not this one.)* This is because $x\in V=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$ means $x=\pmatrix{y\\ 0}$ for some $y\in\mathbb R^k$ (and the $0$ is a zero vector of length $n-k$).